# How to Convert String into decimal in XSLT 2.0 to last two Decimal places

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I want to Convert a string value into decimal by using XSLT 2.0 to last two decimal places.
I want to change the value of Country Code element to decimal.The input string length is fixed i.e 11.

**Input XML:**

```
<GetPersonResponse xmlns="http://www.example.com/xsd/Person_01_RequestResponse_001">
   <Person xsi:type="ns1:Person" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <ns2:PersonId xmlns:ns2="http://www.example.com/xsd/Person_01">4224</ns2:PersonId>
      <ns3:FirstName xmlns:ns3="http://www.example.com/xsd/Person_01">Omer</ns3:FirstName>
      <ns4:LastName xmlns:ns4="http://www.example.com/xsd/Person_01">Khalid</ns4:LastName>
      <ns5:FatherName xmlns:ns5="http://www.example.com/xsd/Person_01">Khalid</ns5:FatherName>
      <ns6:Religion xmlns:ns6="http://www.example.com/xsd/Person_01">Islam</ns6:Religion>
      <ns7:MotherTongue xmlns:ns7="http://www.example.com/xsd/Person_01">Urrdu</ns7:MotherTongue>
      <ns8:DateOfBirth xmlns:ns8="http://www.example.com/xsd/Person_01">1993-02-02</ns8:DateOfBirth>
      <ns9:Gender xmlns:ns9="http://www.example.com/xsd/Person_01" xsi:type="ns1:GenderType">Male</ns9:Gender>
      <ns10:CurrentAddress xmlns:ns10="http://www.example.com/xsd/Person_01" xsi:type="ns1:AddressDetail">
         <ns10:AddressDetailId>194</ns10:AddressDetailId>
         <ns10:StreetNo>5</ns10:StreetNo>
         <ns10:HouseNo>361</ns10:HouseNo>
         <ns10:Town>Johar</ns10:Town>
         <ns10:District>Lahore</ns10:District>
         <ns10:City>Lahore</ns10:City>
         <ns10:State>Punjab</ns10:State>
         <ns10:Country>Pakistan</ns10:Country>
         <ns10:Postal>54046543245</ns10:Postal>
      </ns10:CurrentAddress>
      <ns11:HomeAddress xmlns:ns11="http://www.example.com/xsd/Person_01" xsi:type="ns1:AddressDetail">
         <ns11:AddressDetailId>195</ns11:AddressDetailId>
         <ns11:StreetNo>5</ns11:StreetNo>
         <ns11:HouseNo>361</ns11:HouseNo>
         <ns11:Town>Johar</ns11:Town>
         <ns11:District>Lahore</ns11:District>
         <ns11:City>Lahore</ns11:City>
         <ns11:State>Punjab</ns11:State>
         <ns11:Country>Pakistan</ns11:Country>
         <ns11:Postal>54046543245</ns11:Postal>
      </ns11:HomeAddress>
      <ns12:Height xmlns:ns12="http://www.example.com/xsd/Person_01">6</ns12:Height>
      <ns13:Weight xmlns:ns13="http://www.example.com/xsd/Person_01">100</ns13:Weight>
      <ns14:CNIC xmlns:ns14="http://www.example.com/xsd/Person_01">35302</ns14:CNIC>
      <ns15:ContactInfo xmlns:ns15="http://www.example.com/xsd/Person_01" xsi:type="ns1:ContactDetail">
         <ns15:HomePhone>454545</ns15:HomePhone>
         <ns15:CellPhone>3343434</ns15:CellPhone>
         <ns15:WorkPlacePhone>34343434</ns15:WorkPlacePhone>
         <ns15:Email>omer@gmail.com</ns15:Email>
      </ns15:ContactInfo>
      <ns16:MaritalStatus xmlns:ns16="http://www.example.com/xsd/Person_01">Single</ns16:MaritalStatus>
      <ns17:Nationality xmlns:ns17="http://www.example.com/xsd/Person_01">Pakistani</ns17:Nationality>
   </Person>
   <ResponseCode>PERSON MODULE SUCCESS - 00</ResponseCode>
   <ResponseMessage>Data Fetched Successfully</ResponseMessage>
</GetPersonResponse>
```

**Input XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns="http://www.example.com/xsd/Person_01_RequestResponse_001"
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:m0="http://www.example.com/xsd/Person_01"
xmlns:m="http://www.example.com/cdm/xsd/Person_01_RequestResponse_001"

>

<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates select="//m0:CNIC"/>
</xsl:template>                     
<xsl:template match="//m0:CNIC">
    <m:GetPersonResponse>
<m:PersonId>
<m:NationalIdentityNumber>
<xsl:value-of select="//m0:CNIC"/>
</m:NationalIdentityNumber>

<m:CountryCode>
<xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:value-of select="//m0:Postal"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="type">xs:decimal</xsl:attribute>
</m:CountryCode>
</m:PersonId>
    </m:GetPersonResponse>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Current XML Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<m:GetPersonResponse xmlns:m="http://www.example.com/cdm/xsd/Person_01_RequestResponse_001" xmlns="http://www.example.com/xsd/Person_01_RequestResponse_001" xmlns:m0="http://www.example.com/xsd/Person_01" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <m:PersonId>
      <m:NationalIdentityNumber>35302</m:NationalIdentityNumber>
      <m:CountryCode name="54046543245" type="xs:decimal" />
   </m:PersonId>
</m:GetPersonResponse>
```

**Required XML Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<m:GetPersonResponse xmlns:m="http://www.example.com/cdm/xsd/Person_01_RequestResponse_001" xmlns="http://www.example.com/xsd/Person_01_RequestResponse_001" xmlns:m0="http://www.example.com/xsd/Person_01" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <m:PersonId>
      <m:NationalIdentityNumber>35302</m:NationalIdentityNumber>
      <m:CountryCode name="540465432.45" type="xs:decimal" />
   </m:PersonId>
</m:GetPersonResponse>
```

**Note:** 
There is also an approach in my mind that we can somehow convert our string into decimal and then divide it by 100. But how will it be done?

Comment: Be careful what you wish for. Postal codes are not numbers; converting them to a number will strip any leading zeros which may be part of the code. If you want to insert a period at a predefined position, you can do so by string manipulation.

Comment: thanks for your input but it is just a hypothetical example. I have not shared the exact element which i want to change here.

Comment: We only know what you tell us...

Comment: i apologize for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments, you can do this purely by string manipulation and thus avoid the danger of losing leading/trailing zeros in the process of converting the string to a number:

```
<xsl:variable name="postal" select="//m0:Postal" />
<xsl:value-of select="concat(substring($postal, 1, 9), '.', substring($postal, 10, 2))"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

In XSLT/XPath 2.0 you can convert to `xs:decimal` doing e.g. `xs:decimal(m0:Postal)` and divide using `xs:decimal(m0:Postal) div 100` and format using `format-number(xs:decimal(m0:Postal) div 100, '0.00')`. You would not even need the explicit conversion to `xs:decimal` as with `m0:Postal div 100` you would get a number any way that you could format: `format-number(m0:Postal div 100, '0.00')`. If you use XSLT 2.0 and want to use the explicit conversion with `xs:decimal` then you need to make sure the stylesheet declares `xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but "format-number(m0:Postal div 100, '0.00')"  return "string" and i want decimal.

Comment: But i have tried "//m0:Postal div 100" and it worked for now. So Thanks a lot. But if you know another way kindly inform me.

Comment: @omerkhalid Once again, be careful what you wish for. Dividing a string of digits by 100 will strip not only the leading zeros, but also any trailing zeros to the right of the decimal point.

Comment: i acknowledge your concern but right know i do not have any other option.

Comment: @omerkhalid "*i do not have any other option.*" Of course you do - see my answer.